# Django application (runs in docker container) does not load static files

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm running a django application in a docker container but the static files are not loading. I run the app through the django server itself, with DEBUG activated, the static files folder are in the root of the project, and "django.contrib.staticfiles" is present in my settings, even so, the css and javascript are not found .

Detail, this application works perfectly on my local machine, but when I run it through the Docker container, the static files do not work. Below are details of my project:

**Logs docker container**
[image: Logs do container]

**Console do Chrome**

[image: console do chrome]

**some parts of settings django**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrapform',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_FILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

**docker compose**

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY ./app /code
```

I assigned permission 755 in the static files directory, I changed the ports in docker compose, updated the python/django version and nothing solved it...

Can anyone explain to me what could be going on?

Comment: Who is serving static files now, Django or the web server (apache/nginx/etc)?

Comment: At the moment, Django itself, as the app is not in production yet

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  `docker build`, for example, will not accept that PNG file as an input.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with plain text?

Comment: are you running development server in the container, or a web server? Can you share the config of the web server and check that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in the apps?

Comment: @Marat, I'm running the Django development server in the Docker container and `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in the "INSTALLED_APPS" section of the settings